# Problem with CMake and SQL Build on Mac in Azerothcore

Tags: azerothcore

```
CMake Error at src/cmake/macros/FindMySQL.cmake:302 (message):
  Could not find MySQL headers! Please install the development libraries and
  headers
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:102 (find_package)
```

The problem I'm facing is in the configuration step.
Unsure of what exactly I have to change, is it just the path to the server? I.e.:/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/

I've tried that, and it's throwing the above error.

[https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/macos-core-installation#:~:text=Configuring%20for%20compiling,lib/libcrypto.dylib%22](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I've tried identifying the path of the sql server, installed with Brew. Including that in the script.

Comment: using `whereis mysql` do you get `mysql: /usr/local/bin/mysql`? Probably you do not have this path and cmake does not recognize it

Answer (score 0):

The AzerothCore wiki, as of the writing of this answer, contains a CMake command for MacOS that assumes an Apple Silicon CPU. Homebrew installs packages in `/opt/homebrew` for such Macs, and in `/usr/local` for Intel CPUs.

You would have to change up the paths for a few of the `brew install`'ed libraries:

```bash
export OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)
cmake ../ \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/azeroth-server/  \
-DTOOLS_BUILD=all \
-DSCRIPTS=static \
-DMYSQL_ADD_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include/mysql \
-DMYSQL_LIBRARY=/usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib \
-DREADLINE_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/opt/readline/include \
-DREADLINE_LIBRARY=/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.dylib \
-DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR="$OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR/include" \
-DOPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARIES="$OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR/lib/libssl.dylib" \
-DOPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARIES="$OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR/lib/libcrypto.dylib"
```

<strike>I encountered this issue myself, and put in a pull request to the AC wiki to include this separate CMake command for Intel CPU Macs. Soon, perhaps, this will be remedied in the docs themselves.</strike>

The wiki is now up to date with the information in this answer.